# How to call a internal script function from external js file method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asp.net-mvc-4, call

I am working with the MVC4 application with the aid of an external js file. In the view (.cshtml) file, I have a function which performs an action of creating the row in the grid,
based on the button click.
I have defined the button click in the external .js file.
But, ***when I tried to call the internal script function from that external js file method, it throws an exception saying that, that particular method is not defined.***

I surfed but was not able to find a convincing answer..

Is what I'm trying possible??.. How should I achieve it??

Can any Js expert out there help me with this?...

Thanks All...;)

***EDIT:***

this is in external .js file:

```
    $('#AddRowButton').on('click', function () {
    window.CreateRow();
     }
```

in my view:(.cshtml)

```
    <script>
    function CreateRow()
    {
     // creting row goes here...
    }

    window.CreateRow = CreateRow; //defined like what @joseeight suggested...
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the "internal" function a global function? Is it defined before it is called? Can you show a cut-down version of your code here?

Comment: can you provide how you include `external.js` to your view?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to a scoping issue. The internal script and external must be in a different scopes. The easiest, and hackiest, way to get around this would be to add the internal method to the Window, and access it as such in the external.

```
//Internal script
function myInternalMethod () {
   //some code..
}
window.myInternalMethod = myInternalMethod;
```

Since window is global, and the name is the same, you could either use window.myInternalMethod or myInternalMethod when referencing it in the external scripts.

Comment: Sorry, still no luck...;(

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to see what is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your external file is included below the internal

```
 .......

    <script>

      function createRow(){
         console.log('created');
      }

    </script> 

  <script src = "external.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible only when you call that external js file from html where that internal javascript have..

Example :
a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayAlert(){
        alert('displayAlert');
}
     </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../abc.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
//call the sample() javascript function which is in abc.js
</body>
</html>
```

abc.js

```
function sample(){

displayAlert();

}
```